# Push notification is getting received and taking user to inside the application automatically ?

Tags: ios, swift, push

When user click on push notification app takes user to the respective screen depending upon the push notification information, but in case if so many pushes are coming and user frequently put the app in foreground and background , it automatically takes user to the respective screen, I am not able to determine if user clicked on push notification. Current I am using the following code to determine if user clicked on push notification. normally this check works fine but gets failed in the mentioned scenario.

```
if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        NSLog("App is Inactive......")
        NSLog(" PROCESS PUSH ")
        self.parsePushNotificationInfo(userInfo)
    }
```

Comment: You can't detect Tap on Push Notification, it just launches your application, you should better handle in appDelegate methods `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

Comment: This is what I am asking.How to do that ?

Comment: I already answered, handle your app launches in `AppDelegate` `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationWillEnterForeground` methods.